# Why do Java's Iterator and ListIterator point between elements?

Tags: java, iterator

The [Javadoc for ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) says:

> A `ListIterator` has no current element; its cursor position always lies
>   between the element that would be returned by a call to `previous()` and
>   the element that would be returned by a call to `next()`.

Why was Java's `ListIterator` implemented to point between elements rather than at a current element?  It seems that this makes client code less readable when it has to repeatedly call `getNext()`, `getPrevious()`, so I assume there must be a good reason for the choice.

As a side note, I just wrote [a little library called peekable-arraylist](http://code.google.com/p/peekable-arraylist) that extends `ArrayList`, `Iterator`, and `ListIterator` that provides a `peekAtNext()` and `peekAtPrevious()` methods implemented like:

```
  @Override public synchronized T peekAtNext() {
     T t = next();
     previous();
     return t;
  }
```

Comment: There is a peekable iterator in the Guava library http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  I posted a follow-up question to this on SO: [Is it possible to use Guava's ForwardingListIterator with a PeekingIterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9555695/403455)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the reason can be found in the part of javadoc you didn't quote (emphasis below mine):

> An iterator for lists that allows the programmer to traverse the list in either direction, **modify** the list during iteration...

You see, the intended purpose is to allow usage while list is being modified. Possible modifications apparently include **removal** of the elements.

Now think of what would happen if we remove an element that would be `current()` for iterator - assuming that iterator would have a notion of current element? In this context, the way to implement it without a notion of *current* element makes pretty good sense to me - because that way, iterator does not have to worry about elements removal.

---

It is **important** to note that javadoc does not require interface implementations to be thread safe.

- Because of that, one should not expect correct handling of *modifications* done from different threads - for that, implementation would have to provide additional means to synchronize access, guarantee visibility etc as specified by Java Memory Model per [JSR 133](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133).

What ListIterator is capable of, is handling modifications done from the same thread when iterating. Not all the iterators are like that, [ConcurrentModificationException javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) specifically warn about this:

> ...Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception...

Comment: It also means you don't need a separate `insertBefore` and `insertAfter`, although that's not as big an issue as a `remove`.

Comment: So is the issue that one could concurrently remove and access the current element?  Wouldn't this be the equivalent issue as concurrently calling `next()`?  `remove()` would be `synchronized` as would `getCurrent()`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @glenviewjeff that's a **very** good observation. I also wonder how CME could be handled there - the very stated intent to allow for modifications raises concerns like that. Guess I need to dig deeper. I'm 99.99% sure it's not intended as thread safe, maybe it can only handle concurrent mods done from the same thread (not all iterators are capable of that, you know)

Comment: If you're interested, see my edit.  I implemented and packaged an extension to `ArrayList` to accomplish this.

Comment: @glenviewjeff interesting. In your implementation, are next() and previous() also sync'd? I ask because if not, then other thread can "drill" some unexpected move right into the middle of your current(), making it behave not quite like client would expect... Methods like add() probably would need sync, too

Comment: Now it is.  I synchronized every method based on your logic.

Comment: that's good. BTW if you expect some clients to use your API in single-threaded context, you also have an option to design it in JDK manner, that is to have "main" implementation totally unsynchronized plus a _synchronization wrapper_ for it (refer to [Collections Framework Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html) if you're interested in more details)

Comment: After @kevincline pointed out that Guava has (at least a unidirectional [peeking iterator](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/PeekingIterator.html#next%28%29),) I may delete the Google code project, especially if I get an answer to [my question about how to peek back](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9555695/403455) or if I get an accepted enhancement request to add this to Guava.